# Multiple @todo in phpDoc

Tags: phpdoc, todo

I have multiple todo items I want to add for a function.

What is the correct way to add them in a phpDoc comment block?

I understand that I should use the @todo tag. 
But I am unsure of whether I should use a single @todo tag per item, or one @todo tag for the whole list.

Answer (score 3):

Zero or more `@todo` tags is valid.

[PSR-5: PHPDoc](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/211063eed7f4d9b4514b728d7b1810d9b3379dd1/proposed/phpdoc.md#720-todo)

## Syntax

```
@todo [description]
```

## Example

```
/**
 * Counts the number of items in the provided array.
 *
 * @todo add an array parameter to count
 *
 * @return int Returns the number of elements.
 */
function count()
{
    <...>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[From the standard (emphasis mine)](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/211063eed7f4d9b4514b728d7b1810d9b3379dd1/proposed/phpdoc.md#720-todo):

> The `@todo` tag is used to indicate that **an activity** surrounding the associated "Structural Elements" must still occur. **Each [@todo] tag** MUST be accompanied by a description that communicates the intent of the original author; this could however be as short as providing an issue number.

The way I read this paragraph, there may be multiple `@todo` tags (since the standard refers to "each" instead of "the" tag) and each tag represents a single incomplete behavior (since it reads "an activity", instead of "activities").

This, to me, makes the most sense, as each `@todo` acts as an item in an overall check list. As you complete an item, you "check it off" by deleting the todo item. This would appear very clearly as a line delete in your version control diffs.

However, these are simply annotations, so you may choose of course to ram multiple tasks into one.